# Controlling scroll amount on website

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

I want to recreate the effect used on http://www.apple.com/uk/mac-pro/ whereby one click of the scroll wheel or swipe on the trackpad scrolls the page down to a certain place on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Probably easier to simply have them as animation transitions and intercept the the scroll function, then map the interception to either up or down - assuming you only want one section down at a time.

Answer (score 0):

So if you're using jquery and a scrollTo type plugin you could do something like this:

```
$(function() {
    var scrollPos = 0;
    $(document).scroll(function() {
        var newScrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
        if (newScrollTop > scrollPos) {
            // they are moving down on the page
            $.scrollTo("#DivIdOne");
        } else {
            // they are moving up on the page
            $.scrollTo("#DivIdTwo");
        }

        // set the new scrollPos
        scrollPos = newScrollTop;
    });
});
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [One Page Scroll plugin](https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll) for this effect.

BTW the Apple Mac Pro site is using a video for the animations. You can read more about it in my deconstruction:

- [Apple Mac Pro page deconstructed](http://ihatetomatoes.net/apple-mac-pro-page-deconstructed/)